# Unable to listen on port 33848 when running Jenkins tests

Tags: jenkins, gradle, groovy

I am using jenkins-test-harness to run some tests on my jenkins library code, but when it executes the tests I get the following error for each test :

```
hudson.UDPBroadcastThread#run: Cannot listen to UDP port 33,848, skipping: java.net.SocketException: Can't assign requested address
```

The test will pass (if it should pass), but it then takes about 75 seconds for the jenkins server to shut down.  I believe that these two are related, but I can't work out why I am getting this error.  I have nothing else running on this port.

When I run the tests within a gradle docker container, rather than locally on the command line or inside the IDE (IntelliJ).  This is very frustrating. While it does not change the result of the tests, it takes the running from about 10 minutes to over 1 hour and 15 minutes.

Am I missing a setting which is making this fail?

Answer (score 0):

For me this was caused by Jenkins assuming that the default IP address it would be provided with would be IPv4 when in fact my machine was dual stack, preferring IPv6. I resolved it by ensuring that the `integrationTest` section of my `build.gradle` file had `systemProperties 'java.net.preferIPv4Stack' : true`. A bit like this:

```
integrationTest: {
    /* other statements */
    systemProperties 'java.net.preferIPv4Stack' : true
}
```

I must confess I saw no significant difference to my Jenkins shutdown time. I'd be interested to know if this resolves the error message, and if that resolves your overall issue.